# What is the case of a noun phrase qualifying an adjective in the genitive?

Tags: grammatical-case, declension

> Sie wurde bis zur Spitze des **eine halbe Meile hohen** Roosevelt-Gebäudes gebracht.

Why is this not:

> Sie wurde bis zur Spitze des **einen halben Meilen hohen** Roosevelt-Gebäudes gebracht?

What is the actual case of the phrase, **eine halbe Meile**? Why is this part of what is an overall genitive phrase not declined in the genitive? What factors rule the declension of this part of the genitive phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In noun phrases, the dependants of the noun – that is, determiners and adjectives – agree with it with regard to case and number.

> von ein**em** hoh**en** Gebäude
> innerhalb ein**es** hoh**en** Gebäude**s**
> für dies**es** hoh**e** Gebäude

However, adjectives can have dependants of their own; these stand in a relationship to the adjective, not the noun, and therefore do not agree with the latter. Their form is determined by the adjective or by general rules. In the following examples, *stolz* governs *auf* plus accusative, *ähnlich* governs the dative and *bewußt* governs the genitive.

> Der Wirt ist [stolz auf seinen Service].
> der [auf seinen Service stolz]e Wirt
>
> Das Instrument ist [dem Dudelsack ähnlich].
> ein [dem Dudelsack ähnlich]es Instrument
>
> Die Wissenschaft ist sich [ihrer gesellschaftlichen Verantwortung bewußt].
> eine [ihrer gesellschaftlichen Verantwortung bewußt]e Wissenschaft

All of the noun phrases above can occur in any case without the phrase in brackets, which depends on the adjective, changing in any way.

> für den [auf seinen Service stolz]en Wirt
> der Klang eines [dem Dudelsack ähnlich]en Instruments
> mit einer [ihrer gesellschaftlichen Verantwortung bewußt]en Wissenschaft

Answer (score 2):

**Eine halbe Meile** is accusative, which is the correct case here. Because *Meile* is feminine, the nominative and accusative forms are the same.

If *Meile* is replaced by *Meter*, the accusative form is unambiguous, because *Meter* is masculine:

> Die Mauer ist **einen halben Meter** hoch.

Comment: But why should this be declined accusative and not genitive?

Comment: There is a specific construction using the accusative for measurement specifications, used only with some very specific adjectives, and it's completely independent of the case of the enclosing noun phrase.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adverbial accusative. It denotes a spacial or temporal span. It can be replaced by adverbs, in this case e.g. by «sehr» or «ziemlich». You can ask for it with «wie?».

In this particular case, the adverbial accusative specifies the adjective «hohen».